# How to check using Geofence whether application is going out from state/province

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-geofence

I am newbie to Geofencing of Google play services. The tutorials show that we can create the circular area around the desired `Location` lat/longs and callbacks are triggered when user enters/exit this circular geofence.

But my question is how can I use `Geofence` to check whether use is going out from any state/province because in this scenario, desired area is not circular so we can't provide the radius.

Comment: is polygon are or circular/radios?

Comment: I don't think polygon is circle. but the thing is if `NewYork` is a state and I want that if user goes out from `NewYork` state then I receive any call back

Comment: i know man i'm just asking how could you know area of NEW YORK ?, yes using KML Polygon get it from google!, i have algorithm of that you can check whether your inside of polygon area or not!

Comment: Didn't get the point? is that using `google play services` or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

[Geofence](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder) can only offer fencing on a certain radius of a location. To have an geofence based on a state or shape will have a different approach (which may be difficult)